Is it philosophically justifiable to consider sexual assault worse than murder?
It appears to me that many people consider sexual assault worse than murder. For example,

It seems generally acceptable to make jokes about murder, as long as their are no particularly graphic details. However, telling jokes about sexual assault is considered to be in poor taste.
Many video games involve murdering. The Hitman series is all about murder, and it also happens to be a critically acclaimed game. On the other hand, as far as I can tell, there is no major video game franchise based on the idea of sexual assault. Sexual Assault elements in GTA were not received well.
Most people seem to be fine with eating meat which necessarily involves slaughtering animals. On the other hand, beastiality seems to be frowned upon.
Some people seem to think that rapists should be given the death penalty, suggesting that they think that rape is at least as severe (although not necessarily more) as murder.

The above are just observations. I am trying to understand if the behavior of the people are grounded in good philosophical reasoning.
Should sexual assault be considered worse than murder? What is the philosophical basis for the judgement that sexual assault is worse than murder?
(Please stop Closing this as "opinion-based". I am not asking, "In your opinion, would you agree that sexual assault is worse?". I am asking "Is there philosophical justification to do so?")

Possibly murder is less relatable. Also, the murdered person is not around to feel bad about the jokes.

@andrós “i'm a pacifist, but i am within my rights to kill you to stop you raping me” That sounds like a contradiction.

This is more about psychology than philosophy.

@IdiosyncraticSoul not really this is dealing with the morality and ethics of certain action as seen in society. This is clearly philosophy?!

There are some circumstances where killing is, arguably, morally justified, self-defense, survival, war conditions, killing Hitler, etc. Many violent videogames at least nod towards such circumstances, killing 'bad' people or 'soulless' creatures (as many consider animals). It is much harder to come up with circumstances justifying debasement, in particular, rape, and the victim has to endure the suffering during and after whereas with the killing she is no more. So the empathy is stronger, the condemnation is harder to defer psychologically, and the social taboo is easier to maintain.

@Howwhye Why murder jokes are funnier than rape jokes seems more about psychology. I find jokes about either equally not funny.

@IdiosyncraticSoul Oh I see what you mean. I thought you were talking about the topic of discussing which was more worse rather than discussing the humor aspect of the question.

It's cultural. In the ancient world a man who forcibly took a thousand   «wives» was considered a real man. The modern «liberal»  west: If murder were genuinely punishable Nobel  «peace» winners would hang.

I think this question needs serious revision. The relevant philosophy question is "what arguments and counterarguments have been advanced for/against X?" "What do people in general feel about X" (sociology) and "why do they feel that way" (psychology) are off topic.

@andrós Since, per your definition, pacifism is the opposition to violence – including violent defense – you should see now how you cannot be both a pacifist and kill a rapist in self-defense.

@andrós And, to quote properly, put quotes within quotation marks and provide a source (Wikipedia in your case, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacifism).

Why is this closed? It seems like a very legitimate philosophical question to determine the moral ranking of two things

@JonathanZ If you want that as an argument pls also apply it to 20 more questions at random out here

@andrós The Wikipedia article you quoted from makes it very clear that pacifists reject violence “unconditional[ly]”; that they reject “all forms of warfare” (emphasis mine). That doesn’t leave room for defense. Those ‘limited’ pacifists you speak of advocate pacifism so diluted to be meaningless; they just share the non-pacifist, commonsense view that (proportionate) violence in self-defense is okay.

I personally agree that there should be no question that murder is worse than rape. Deep down  most people really agree. Even women. Simple proof. More women submit to rapists pointing guns at them than choose to be murdered by them.
That said, it is treated in many ways worse than murder. There is no murder registry for murderers who were released from jail like there is a sex offenders registry. Unless a murder was done in a gruesome manner a guy who was in a fight with his neighbor and murdered him in a fit of rage would not be treated with the same revulsion as someone who raped his neighbor in a drunken stupor by most people.
The reason may be  that no one survives a murder. The victim is gone and can no longer speak up for himself. Conversely a rape survivor is still alive  and dealing with the emotional pain afterwards. As such there are  rape victims advocating so  that others should not share their fate. They  bring into the public conscious the pain they feel as a result of being a victim of that crime. Murder victims rarely have anyone speaking up them afterwards. There are no murder survivor groups lobbying for murder victims and bringing their pain to the public conscious.  As such it doesn't have the emotional place in society that rape does

I agree with your answer normatively. But not descriptively.  Speaking factually, positions like this are inconsistent unless one takes an explicitly pacifist stand re. wars. Nevertheless I dont consider inconsistency in ethical matters to be a big issue. So upvoted. Trouble is everyone is pacifist... except when it comes to their favorite enemies!!

Mothers Against Drunk Driving and similar groups essentially speak up for 'murder' victims.

@andrós: Killing a rapist is not the same as killing an innocent person, and so can't be compared to raping an innocent person. Your comment in fact supports this post, since you are only willing to take 15 yr off your own life in exchange for not being raped, so presumably you consider suffering from rape to be roughly equivalent to losing 15 yr of your life, not your whole life.

@‍andrós: Your comment does not make sense to me.

I don't know that it is seen as worse, but if so one may consider these as possible reasons:

death = done.  Victim is gone and forevermore unaware.  Game over for them.

rape = violation.  Victim lives remainder of life able to remember being violated.  Lives knowing you may again be violated.  Knowing violation can and does occur.  It's real.  Not talk.  Lives in possible fear.  Possible misery or fear or depression.  Obsession with past.  A changed, different person with a different look in their eyes.


That may be why.  The individual goes from liking and believing in justice and safety and goodness... to knowing the world isnt always fair and people aint all good.  A much darker reality to live with.
Some see death as peaceful.
(Some think its not the end, but we aren't going to entertain that here).

If you consider the general case of jokes about death, it's in a quite different category, because death happens to us all. So we make light of it with jokes – when appropriate, but joking about death in the presence of someone who has recently lost a loved one is highly insensitive.
